# Delphi TNetHTTPClient Authorization not working

Tags: rest, delphi, authorization

I have the following C# code that works, ie. I get the expected result from the server.

```
static async Task GetObjectInfo()
{
  HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
  {
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')
  });
            
  string requestUrl = "http://<ipaddress>/rest/api/info/9C145D739F73";
  Console.WriteLine("Url: " + requestUrl);
  HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
  {
    string aresult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(aresult);
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
  }
}
```

However, I need to do the same in Delphi (RAD Studio 10.3), but the server always responds with `You do not have permission to view this directory or page.`

I used the TNetHTTPClient

```
AUrl := 'http://<ipaddress>/rest/api/info/9C145D739F73';
memResult.Lines.Text := NetHTTPClient1.Get(AUrl, nil).ContentAsString;
```

and in the `NetHTTPClient1AuthEvent` I have

```
procedure TForm1.NetHTTPClient1AuthEvent(const Sender: TObject;
  AnAuthTarget: TAuthTargetType; const ARealm, AURL: string; var AUserName,
  APassword: string; var AbortAuth: Boolean;
  var Persistence: TAuthPersistenceType);
begin
  if AnAuthTarget = TAuthTargetType.Server then
    begin
      AUserName := 'USERNAME';
      APassword := 'PASSWORD';
    end;
end;
```

If I debug the code, the `AnAuthTarget = TAuthTargetType.Server` so the username and password is set. What can I try next?

Comment: Which error do you get? What is the value of AbortAuth argument. If not already false, set it to false.

Comment: AbortAuth = False; I do not get an error code, `ContentAsString` shows that the authorisation seems to fail.